# Understanding proof of "if $f$ is non-negative, then it is the supremum of simple functions."

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

I am studying measure theory based on the book "Probability and Measure Theory" by Ash and have a question about understanding one of the theorems. Here it goes:

(Page 43) Theorem 1.5.9 (d) If $h \ge 0$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$, then $$\int_B h \ d\mu = \sup \left\{ \int_B s \ d\mu \; | \; 0 \le s \le h, s \text{ is simple} \right\}$$

*Proof:*

If $0 \le s \le h$, then $\int_B s \ d\mu \le \int_B h d\mu$ (take this as given; previous theorem). Hence, $$\int_B h \ d\mu \ge \sup \left\{\int_B s \ d\mu \ | \ 0 \le s \le h \right\}.$$

If $t$ is simple such that $0 \le t \le h I_B$ ($I$ denotes indicator function), then $t = tI_B \le h$ so
$$\color{red}{\int_\Omega t \ d\mu \le \sup \left\{\int_\Omega s I_B \ d\mu \ | \ 0 \le s \le h, s \text{ is simple} \right\}.}$$ Take the
$\color{blue}{\text{sup over } t \text{ to obtain } \int_B h \ d\mu \le \sup \left\{\int_B s \ d\mu \ | \ 0 \le s \le h,  s \text{ is simple} \right\}}$.

My questions are as follows:

1. (Red part.) We could extend this to the below, right? $$\int_\Omega t \ d\mu \le \sup \{ \cdots\} \le \int_\Omega hI_B \ d\mu\le \int_\Omega h \ d\mu$$
2. (Blue part.) Then, I am not sure how the last inequality holds. Moreover, I am not sure how taking the sup over $t$ results in that inequality.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

---

Read @angryavian's comment and come back to the edits below.

**EDIT 1:** (What we know from above: $t$ is simple function s.t. $0 \le t \le hI_B$.)

If the extension follows (under Q1), by taking the sup over $t$, we would just have that extension. In other words:

$$\sup_t \int_\Omega t \ d\mu = \sup \left\{ \int_\Omega sI_B \ d\mu \; | \; 0 \le s \le h, s \text{ is simple} \right\} \le \int_\Omega hI_B \ d\mu\le \int_\Omega h \ d\mu$$
Equivalently, we would not have
$$\int_B h \ d\mu \le \sup \left\{\int_B s \ d\mu \ | \ 0 \le s \le h,  s \text{ is simple} \right\} $$

**EDIT 2:**
Or, is it that by taking the sup over $t$, we have the following steps?

*Step 1*. By definition of integral of non-neg function $h$, and following from our previous proof:
$$
\int_\Omega t \ d\mu \le \sup \left\{\int_\Omega s I_B \ d\mu \ | \ 0 \le s \le h, s \text{ is simple} \right\} = \int_\Omega hI_B \ d\mu = \int_B h \ d\mu
$$

*Step 2*. Taking sup over $t$:
$$
\int_\Omega t \ d\mu \le \sup \left\{\int_\Omega s I_B \ d\mu \ | \ 0 \le s \le h, s \text{ is simple} \right\} \le \sup_t \int_\Omega t \ d\mu, \text{ where } 0 \le t \le hI_B,
$$

because the $\{ \cdots \}$ constrains to $I_B$, and henceforth the result follows as $\sup \{\cdots \} = \int_B h \ d\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, yes that is true, but I am not sure why that would be helpful in proving $\int_B h \, d\mu \le \sup\{\cdots\}$.

For your second question: This follows from the definition of the integral (see page 38). Specifically, $\int_\Omega hI_B \, d\mu$ is **defined** as $\sup_t \int_\Omega t \, d\mu$ for $0 \le t \le hI_B$. The purpose of proving this theorem (Theorem 1.5.9(d)) is to show that essentially the same statement holds if you replace $\Omega$ with a measurable set $B$.

---

You already have
$$\int_\Omega t \, d\mu \le \sup\left\{\int_\Omega sI_B \mid 0 \le s \le h, \text{$s$ simple}\right\}.$$
This inequality holds for any $t$ satisfying $0 \le t \le hI_B$. So if we take the supremum over all such $t$, the left-hand side becomes $\int_\Omega hI_B \, d\mu$, and inequality still holds with the right-hand side unchanged.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I am sorry but am still not fully clear :(  I have edited my original post to explain my uncertainty. Could you please give me an insight? Thank you!

Comment: @discretechoice Added some more details.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know fully understand it. Guess I over complicated it. Thank you once again :)

Comment: Glad to help :) @discretechoice